# Send message from server to client with dnode

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets, dnode

A couple of month ago I discovered nowjs and dnode and finally used nowjs (and https://github.com/Flotype/nowclient) for client / server bidirectional communication.

nowclient enables nowjs communication between 2 node processes (instead of between a node process and a browser for nowjs out of the box). I was then able to send data from the client to the server and from the server to the client. I now use node 0.6.12 and it's kind of painful to use node 0.4.x to run the client.

I'm giving a closer look to dnode and I'm not really sure how the server to client communication is working. Is it possible that the server sends a direct message to the client ? The idea is to have a client to register on the server (at first connection) and enable the server to contact the client when it needs to.

From what I understand, calling a method on the server is possible if the client has requested something from the server at first place. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dnode uses a symmetric protocol so either side can define functions that the opposing side can call. There are 2 basic approaches you can take.

The first way is to define a register function on the server side and to pass in a callback from the client.

**server:**

```
var dnode = require('dnode');

dnode(function (remote, conn) {
    this.register = function (cb) {
        // now just call `cb` whenever you like!
        // you can call cb() with whichever arguments you like,
        // including other callbacks!

        setTimeout(function () {
            cb(55);
        }, 1337);
    };
}).listen(5000)
```

**client:**

```
var dnode = require('dnode');

dnode.connect('localhost', 5000, function (remote, conn) {
    remote.register(function (x) {
        console.log('the server called me back with x=' + x);
    });
});
```

or instead you could directly call the client from the server in a symmetric fashion once the method exchange is complete:

**server:**

```
var dnode = require('dnode');

dnode(function (remote, conn) {
    conn.on('ready', function () {
        remote.foo(55);
    });
}).listen(5000);
```

**client:**

```
var dnode = require('dnode');
dnode(function (remote, conn) {
    this.foo = function (n) {
        console.log('the server called me back with n=' + n);
    };
}).connect('localhost', 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. Can a client be connected to a server and wait for incoming call coming from the server ? Also, is there a client identifier that can the used server side ?

Comment: I used conn.id and remote to keep track of the clients. That's working really great.

Comment: Just realized that this answer is from substack him self. <3 dat guy - so many awesome modules!

Comment: Yup he rocks! I'm trying to figure out how to get this working with a udp stream, but the events occur after the initial load. It seems all the examples are for communication that happens on first load (d.on()). Any of you know how to do this for subsequent events?